# How do I find out what writes to an address using C++?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assembly

I have an address that get's writen to 1000x  per second by 300 different instructions. How can I use c++ to find out the last instruction to write to an address?

I already have made it so it alerts me the instance a specific value is written to an address, but how can I make it print the last instruction address that wrote that specific value?

I would do this in a debugger but all of the debuggers I've found cannot handle doing a conditional breakpoint on an address that changes 1000x per second without freezing the program.

If I can't do this in C++, what are other ways that I can do this? I need to find what address instruction writes a specific value to a memory address that receives over 1000 writes per second from different addresses.

Update:

I am using Windows 7 x32 for those wondering.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  There isn't a direct mapping between your C++ code and the assembly generated by the compiler.  So I don't think you can do this at the C++ level.

Comment: You can't use C++.  You need a performance monitor that will do sampling.

Comment: You can use gdb to set a condition breakpoint, try it.

Comment: Setting data breakpoints are possible on x86 processors. Windbg and other debugger expose this functionality through their command. E.g. windbg's ba command http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553451(v=vs.85).aspx - you could associate "k; g;" command with the break point so you don't have to type them each time when break point hits.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [pin](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool). Briefly, pin allows you to instrument your code at the x86 instruction level, allowing you to track reads and/or writes as you please. I've used it myself to model cache performance and found it fairly fast.

Comment: Is there any tutorials relating to this? I did a bit of googling and couldn't find any so I really have no idea how to start to even try. I've downloaded pin, at that much.

Comment: I've used it on Linux, but on Windows, it should still work, so here goes: Get the "pinatrace" tool building from source and running (it's an address tracer) on your platform. Try it on a simple program (iterate through an int array... are you getting addresses that increase by 4 each time?). When you have sanity-checked it, start modifying it to selectively trace based on the address that you want to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

> already have made it so it alerts me the instance a specific value is written to an address, but how can I make it print the last instruction address that wrote that specific value?

If it's just for one-off debugging, have the code that alerts system/popen `pstack` (http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pstack1.html) or similar - some external program that dumps your call stack.  Exactly which program to use is highly OS dependent, and you've said nothing of your environment.  (This is a common technique for generating call stacks from signal handlers after invalid memory accesses etc.)